# Как обновлять или сбросить выбранные данные в связанных combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, combobox

Есть 3 связанных combobox имеющих привязку к бд. В кажом combobox прописан linq запрос, с выборкой данных в бд. При выборе данных в 1 combobox  происходит сортировка с помощью linq запроса и результат выборки предаётся во 2 combobox по аналогии данные из 2 прередаются в 3 combobox. Допустим я хочу изменить выбор в 1 combobox, как сделать так, чтобы данные сбросились из 2 и 3?

```
 public void Ser_CPU_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        ser = Ser_CPU.SelectedItem.ToString();
        ser = ser.Remove(0, 11);
        ser = ser.Replace("}", "");
        var query3 = (
               from CPU in dataEntities.CPU
               where CPU.Manufacturer == proizvod && CPU.Series == ser
               select new { CPU.Soket }).Distinct();
        Sok_CPU.ItemsSource = query3.ToList();
    }

    public void Sok_CPU_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        sok = Sok_CPU.SelectedItem.ToString();
        sok = sok.Remove(0, 10);
        sok = sok.Replace("}", "");
        var query4 = (
               from CPU in dataEntities.CPU
               where CPU.Manufacturer == proizvod && CPU.Series == ser && CPU.Soket == sok
               select new { CPU.Model_CPU }).Distinct();
        Mod_CPU.ItemsSource = query4.ToList();

    }

    public void Mod_CPU_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        kod = Mod_CPU.SelectedItem.ToString();
        kod = kod.Remove(0, 14);
        kod = kod.Replace("}", "");
        var query5 = (
               from CPU in dataEntities.CPU
               where CPU.Manufacturer == proizvod && CPU.Series == ser && CPU.Soket == sok && CPU.Model_CPU == kod
               select new {CPU.Energy_consumption }).Distinct();
                Energy_CPU.ItemsSource = query5.ToList();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так, это спровоцирует вызов обработчика `SelectionChanged` у целевого комбобокса.

```csharp
Sok_CPU.ItemsSource = query3.ToList();
Sok_CPU.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

---

**Обновление**

Так как ваше решение не гибкое, а в комментариях вы указали формат данных `{ MOD_CPU=3600 }`, я попробовал реализовать универсальную функцию обновления комбобоксов. Проверяйте.

```csharp
private void UpdateCombo(ComboBox currentCombo, ComboBox nextCombo)
{
    string text = currentCombo.SelectedItem?.ToString().Split('=')[1].Trim().Split('}')[0].Trim() ?? "";
    if (text.Length > 0)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> query;
        switch (nextCombo.Name)
        {
            case nameof(Sok_CPU):
                ser = text;
                query = (
                    from CPU in dataEntities.CPU
                    where CPU.Manufacturer == proizvod && CPU.Series == ser
                    select new { CPU.Soket }).Distinct();
                nextCombo.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
                UpdateCombo(nextCombo, Mod_CPU); // рекурсия для обновления по цепочке
                break;
            case nameof(Mod_CPU):
                sok = text;
                query = (
                    from CPU in dataEntities.CPU
                    where CPU.Manufacturer == proizvod && CPU.Series == ser && CPU.Soket == sok
                    select new { CPU.Model_CPU }).Distinct();
                nextCombo.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
                UpdateCombo(nextCombo, Energy_CPU);
                break;
            case nameof(Energy_CPU):
                kod = text;
                query = (
                    from CPU in dataEntities.CPU
                    where CPU.Manufacturer == proizvod && CPU.Series == ser && CPU.Soket == sok && CPU.Model_CPU == kod
                    select new { CPU.Energy_consumption }).Distinct();
                nextCombo.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
                break;
            default:
                query = Array.Empty<object>();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public void Ser_CPU_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateCombo(Ser_CPU, Sok_CPU);
}

public void Sok_CPU_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateCombo(Sok_CPU, Mod_CPU);
}

public void Mod_CPU_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateCombo(Mod_CPU, Energy_CPU);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109036/discussion-on-answer-by-aepot--------).